# Package built using rollup is not working with html script

Tags: javascript, package, rollup, rollupjs

We have an application in Typescript and the package is built using rollup. My package is working fine with React and Angular application and no complaints.

I want to use my package in simple html application. When I tried including the js file in the script tag I'm facing issues with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module index.js`

Tried specifying type=module in the script tag but still facing issue

I want to know is there any issue with the way my package is build using rollup to support for including in script tag ( As it working fine with react application)?